# Applying Instr function in reverse order using sqldf

Tags: r, dataframe, substring, sqldf

I have this data

```
           Quiz_answers
1 `a1,a5,a2,a3`Positive
2    `a1,a2,a4`Negative
3 `a1,aa4,a2,a3`Neutral
4    `a1,a2,a4`Positive
5    `a1,a2,a4`Negative
6    `a1,a2,a3`Negative
7     `a1,a7,a3`Neutral
8    `a1,a2,a5`Negative
```

On the column Quiz_Answer when trying to extract string after the last back-tick character by passing `-1` argument to INSTR gives me error: *wrong number of arguments to function instr()*.
I am able to run it without using `-1` as a argument but it then searches from beginning by default.

```
Quiz_answers<-c("`a1,a5,a2,a3`Positive","`a1,a2,a4`Negative","`a1,aa4,a2,a3`Neutral","`a1,a2,a4`Positive","`a1,a2,a4`Negative","`a1,a2,a3`Negative","`a1,a7,a3`Neutral","`a1,a2,a5`Negative")
data<-data.frame(Quiz_answers);
qr<-sqldf("SELECT substr(Quiz_answers, instr(Quiz_answers,'`',-1) + 1) AS HistoryAnswer from data")
```

- Is there any other way to do this using sqldf select query?

Comment: Also, which database are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oracle

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have loaded the database table in dataframe and then querying those dataframe using sqldf. My database is Oracle. I am loading the table in dataframe using dbReadTable function from RJDBC package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) H2 backend** If you use the H2 database backend to sqldf then the select statement in the question will work as written in the question:

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)  # if H2 database is loaded sqldf will notice it and use it

sqldf("SELECT 
         substr(Quiz_answers, instr(Quiz_answers,'`',-1) + 1) AS HistoryAnswer 
       FROM data")
```

**1a)** H2 also supports the [regexp_replace](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#regexp_replace) and [regexp_like](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#regexp_like) functions in a select statement.

**2) SQLite backend** If you are using the default SQLite backend to sqldf then trim off the first backtick from the left in which case the original second backtick becomes the first and we can use `instr`.  (Alternately we could use `substr(Quiz_answers, 2)` in place of `ltrim(...)` .)

```
library(sqldf)  # if no other database is loaded sqldf uses the RSQLite backend

sqldf("SELECT 
         substr(Quiz_answers, instr(ltrim(Quiz_answers, '`'), '`') + 2) AS HistoryAnswers
       from data")
```

**2a)** An alternative if the part between the backticks contains only a, digits, comma and backtick is the following

```
sqldf("select ltrim(Quiz_answers, '`a1234567890,') as HistoryAnswers from data")
```

(If in reality it could contain any letter but not an upper case letter it would still work if you replace a with all the letters of the alphabet in the `ltrim` second argument.)

**2b)** Yet another approach with SQLite would be:

```
sqldf("select 
    case
      when Quiz_answers like '%Positive' then 'Positive'
      when Quiz_answers like '%Negative' then 'Negative'
      else 'Neutral'
    end as HistoryAnswers 
  from data")
```

This would also work under H2.

**2c)** or if it is OK to return +1, 0, -1 rather than Positive, Neutral, Negative then:

```
sqldf("select 
    (Quiz_answers like '%Positive') - (Quiz_answers like '%Negative') as HistoryAnswers 
  from data")
```

This would work in H2 if we cast the two booleans to int.

**2d)** Another approach is to reverse the string using `reverse` like this:

```
sqldf("select 
   substr(Quiz_answers, length(Quiz_answers) - instr(reverse(Quiz_answers), '`') + 2) 
      as HistoryAnswers 
  from data")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to match the back-tick at the start of the string followed by zero or more character that are not a back-tick followed by a backtick and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^`[^`]*`", "", data$Quiz_answers)
#[1] "Positive" "Negative" "Neutral"  "Positive" "Negative" "Negative" "Neutral"  "Negative"
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because the OP's requested operation is exactly the sort of thing you really _don't_ want to end up having to do in a database.  I'd rather be doing this in R +1.

Comment: I tried this qr<-sqldf("SELECT sub('^`[^`]*`', '', data$Quiz_answers) AS HistoryAnswer from data")` it gives me error `Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such function: sub.` In comments the backticks are not visible but i have used them

Comment: @Akki Why do you have to do this `sqldf`  Without that it works fine and should be faster

Comment: I have oversimplified the question to make my problem clear. My actual columns is part of a a join query in sqldf. Thus i want to achieve it using sqldf

Comment: @akrun How should i apply sub on this data value: 4 to 6 months\`0 to 10%\`3 to 5 years\`1\`Disagree`Potential return of 12% per annum\`5%-10% per annum\`ds\`Agree\`Future Lifestyle Improvement\`INR 5,00,00 to INR 10,00,000\`No\`33\`Balanced agressive

Comment: @Akki Could you please update on your post as it is not clear from the comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157638/discussion-between-akki-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

In practice I might go with the answer given by @akrun, but here is a query which should work on Oracle

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE (Quiz_answers, '`.*`', '')
FROM data
```

Or in R code:

```
qr <- sqldf("REGEXP_REPLACE (Quiz_answers, '`.*`', '') FROM data")
```

Here is a demo showing that the above query works correctly:

## Demo

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE would work only if i directly query the database which is not what i am trying to do. Please read my last comment.

Comment: @Akki If you're not directly querying the database, then just go with the answer by akrun ; if you _are_ doing this from a query, then my answer should work for you, regardless of how many joins you have.